# Drawbacks to redefining method in precompiled header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a lot of calls to `NSLog(...)`. I need to change all of these calls to `CLSNSLog(...)`.

So I added this to my precompiled header (.pch):

```
#import <CrashlyticsFramework/Crashlytics.h>
#define NSLog(...) CLSNSLog(__VA_ARGS__);
```

Everything works. I don't see any drawbacks to this -- the team can continue to use NSLog(...) and I can revert pretty easily.

But am I missing anything, or are there any design issues this will create later on?

Answer (score 2):

The only issue I can see is that it may be confusing. `NSLog` is a commonly used function provided by Foundation framework. But you change it globally to something else and new developer may not aware of it.

Other than that, it should be fine since the header/define won't change often.